# Is there an equivalent to Mozilla Prism that uses the Internet Explorer engine?

Tags: firefox, browser, internet-explorer, web, mozilla-prism

I'm looking for something similar to [Mozilla Prism](http://prism.mozilla.com/) that will generate a minimal desktop application from a website, but that uses the Internet Explorer engine instead of the Firefox engine.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: *Why* do you want to use the IE rendering engine?

Comment: @jtbandes: I don't *want* to, I *have* to: http://superuser.com/questions/4110/why-are-you-still-using-ie6/4119#4119

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I am aware, the closest you're going to get to such an application at the current moment is with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and enter

```
mshta.exe http://www.google.com/
```

There is however no navigation, no menus, no nothing. It doesn't integrate with anything, and is as simple as it can get. You get your website opened, that's it.

The way to use this would be to create a shortcut, add a nice icon and voila, you've at least got something.

**Warning:** There are no Internet Explorer features with this application. It uses the Trident rendering engine, and that's all. If you can use something else, please do.

Comment: You'd better not put 4 w's in the address for google, or it might not work.